# Autofac Interception Not Working

Tags: autofac

I cannot get autofac to intercept. I have the following setup in my .net core application:

// Logger created: //

```
public class Logger : IInterceptor
{
    public void Intercept(IInvocation invocation)
    {
        // Logging removed for now
        var watch = System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch.StartNew();  // Added break point here
        invocation.Proceed(); 
        watch.Stop();
        var executionTime = watch.ElapsedMilliseconds;
    }
}
```

// Class Created: //

```
[Intercept(typeof(Logger))]
public class ServiceProxy: ServiceInterface
{
    public User GetUser(String username, String password)
    {
        var service = ServiceHelper.GetODataClaimService();
        var query = from a in service.Users
                            select a;
        var dsq = query.ToDataServiceQuery<User>();
        var result = dsq.ToListSync<User>();
        var user = result.FirstOrDefault();
        return user;
    }
}
```

// Interface Created: //

```
public interface ServiceInterface
{
    User GetUser(String username, String password);
}
```

// Interception Configuration //

```
public class Interceptor
{
    public static void Configure()
    {
        var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
        builder.Register(a => new Logger());
        builder.RegisterType<ServiceProxy>().As<ServiceInterface>().EnableInterfaceInterceptors().InterceptedBy(typeof(Logger));  // Tried removing intercepted by
        var container = builder.Build();
        var worker = container.Resolve<ServiceInterface>();
        builder.Build()
    }
}
```

I put a break point in the logger to see if it ever enters that block of code.
It never does. What am I missing here?
I've tried quite a few configurations but nothing seems to work.
Also - The Configure method is invoked from application Startup..

Please advise.

Answer (score 0):

Using your posted code I can't reproduce the issue you describe. The interceptor gets hit and everything works fine.

However, I had to make three changes to try it out.

1. I switched the `ServiceInterface.GetUser` method to just return a string. I don't have your data objects or anything. I'd recommend removing that stuff from the repro in the question if it's not important to the overall question.
2. I removed the `InterceptedBy(typeof(Logger))`. That's not needed with attributes, though I do see the comment that says you tried that.
3. I removed the duplicate `builder.Build()` from the `Interceptor.Configure()` method. That will actually throw an exception on trying to build the container a second time.

Item #3 concerns me since it means the repro is potentially missing some of the stuff causing the issue (and maybe that you didn't try the repro before posting it?).

Anyway, here's a fully working console app that uses your code:

```
    using Autofac;
    using Autofac.Extras.DynamicProxy;
    using Castle.DynamicProxy;
    using System;

    namespace InterfaceInterception
    {
        class Program
        {
            static void Main(string[] args)
            {
                var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
                builder.Register(a => new Logger());
                builder.RegisterType<ServiceProxy>().As<ServiceInterface>().EnableInterfaceInterceptors();
                var container = builder.Build();
                var worker = container.Resolve<ServiceInterface>();
                Console.WriteLine(worker.GetUser("", ""));
                Console.ReadKey();
            }
        }

        public class Logger : IInterceptor
        {
            public void Intercept(IInvocation invocation)
            {
                var watch = System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch.StartNew();
                invocation.Proceed();
                watch.Stop();
                var executionTime = watch.ElapsedMilliseconds;
                Console.WriteLine("Execution time: {0}", executionTime);
            }
        }

        [Intercept(typeof(Logger))]
        public class ServiceProxy : ServiceInterface
        {
            public string GetUser(String username, String password)
            {
                return "a";
            }
        }

        public interface ServiceInterface
        {
            string GetUser(String username, String password);
        }
    }
```

The console output will be like:

```
Execution time: 1
a
```

You can put a breakpoint in the interceptor and it will get hit. The console output shows it gets hit, too. So... there's something else going on, possibly in your app code, which is causing the issues you're seeing. The repro here looks [basically] good.

Answer (score 0):

I realized after I posted this that all of the examples on the web simply showed the builder being created and directly executing a method.  I was assuming that there was interception occurring similar to that of ContextBoundedObjects / Remote Services, but that isn't the case.  In order to get this to work, I had to use dependency injection to inject ServiceInterface into the constructor of my class.  Effectively the builder intercepted this and passed in Castle.Proxies.ServiceInterfaceProxy.

```
public class LoginController : Controller
{
    ServiceInterface proxy;

    public LoginController(ServiceInterface _proxy)
    {
        proxy = _proxy;
    }
}
```

This required a few additional things that weren't in the examples I found online:

1. Include Autofac dependency injection

   using Autofac.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
2. Ensure Autofac is included in the WebHostBuilder

   ```
    public class Program
   {
       public static void Main(string[] args)
       {
           var host = new WebHostBuilder()
               .UseKestrel()
               .ConfigureServices(services => services.AddAutofac())
               .UseContentRoot(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
               .UseIISIntegration()
               .UseStartup<Startup>()
               .Build();
           host.Run();
       }
   }
   ```
3. Configure Services must be changes to return IServiceProvider
4. When setting up the builder, ensure builder.Populate(services) is included

   ```
   public IServiceProvider ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
       {
           services.AddMvc().AddJsonOptions(options => options.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new DefaultContractResolver());
           services.AddKendo();
           services.AddDistributedMemoryCache();
           services.AddSession(options =>
           {
               options.IdleTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(Convert.ToInt32(Configuration["SessionTimeout"]));
               options.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
           });
           return ConfigureProvider(services);
       }

       public IServiceProvider ConfigureProvider(IServiceCollection services)
       {
           var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
           builder.Populate(services);
           builder.Register(a => new LogInterception());
           builder.Register(a => new CircuitInterception());
           builder.RegisterType<ServiceProxy>().As<ServiceInterface>().EnableInterfaceInterceptors();
           Container = builder.Build();
           return new AutofacServiceProvider(this.Container);
       }
   ```